# Static noise Nvidia Linux

Tags: linux, graphics-card, fps

Firstly say that I have tried the search but couldn't exactly find a similar issue. Probably for my lack of vocabulary on this matter therefore apologies if there is indeed a post asking the same.

I have a weird issue that, whilst I believe not really important, is quite annoying.

On a Debian machine , with a GTX 970 and the latest 375 Nvidia drivers installed via the repositories, the card woks at normal speeds and fantastically on the desktop.

However, when running a game that isn't graphically demanding*, the card goes bananas and starts making a high pitch noise. Seems a bit like static though not sure if that's the right term for it. For what I've read this could be due to the graphics card throwing a lot of frames per second, but again, not sure if that's correct. Also saw somewhere it could be as a result of the fan speed and the card usage at 100%.

Funny enough, with exactly same machine, if I boot into Windows this hardly happens albeit I encountered it with the Grim Fandango Remastered version for instance.

I have tried to force the "Sync to VBlank" option from the nvidia-settings and use the libstrangle script from GitHub to not avail. Also, just now at work thus not tried yet, I've read here and on Google about Bumblebee. Is this anything you would recommend? Can be used on a Desktop or only laptops?

Lastly, the board has an integrated Intel CPU that at the moment is BIOS disabled. Could I enable it and then choose which one to use at startup? Wouldn't be a problem with two different drivers installed?

- Noticed the sound with games such as the previously mentioned Grim Fandango Remastered, Dead Synchronicity, Hot Tin Roof and other 2D or with old 3D capabilities games. With games like Tomb Raider or Life is Strange doesn't happen.

Can I limit the usage on the graphics card somehow? Are there any FPS limiters, equivalents to FRAPS, for Linux? Do you have any recommendations? Have any of you suffered this same issue?

Thank you very much for your help!

EDIT: It seems to be coil whine when, indeed, the card is rendering a huge load of FPS. At the moment I'm trying to find out why libstrangle does not work as some people on the internet have reported it almost fully functional.

Comment: Where is the sound coming from? Via audio port / headphones? Or is it a mechanical noise on the board of the card?

Comment: It's coming from the rig itself.

Comment: Yes, where? Rig meaning computer case or something?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, from the case. From the graphics card to be precise but can't find whether is the fans or something else.

Comment: Sounds like noise due to a fan or something. This probably isn't the right site for your question.

Comment: Not even if via software with libstrangle can be fixed? Sorry in that case.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand? I had a similar problem with a computer with a xeon part which turned out to be due to a combination of components - when I changed the PSU, the problem went away. But if you aren't hearing a whine from an audio port then I guess this might be something different.

Comment: What I mean is that running a game with 60FPS limit the high pitch sound stops. That noise is the same that coil whine some people show on youtube coming from motherboard. Therefore I need to find a way now to make all games run with a limit to 60fps... if that make sense?

Comment: Oh I see - that is very weird. I don't think it would be possible to force games to run at a particular rate especially since frame rate is dependent on the computer rendering a frame in a particular time, and that is dependent on the complexity of the frame to be rendered. (How many objects to be drawn in a game etc...)

Comment: A whine means either the fan, or a component on the video card called a "capacitor" are having trouble, most likely. Capacitors store power like batteries and then release the energy in a very controlled way, and you'll find them on most computer components. When they begin to fail they'll sometimes whine or "sing".

Comment: You shouldn't edit your question to include an answer in the question, or "solved" in the question title, or similar edits. Rather, you should post a self-answer and mark it as accepted. That keeps the separation between the question and the answer clear, and allows the communtiy to vote on the answer distinct from the question that it answers. See [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) in our site's [help] for more details.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that. Sorry, will fix it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script libstrangle, found in GitHub [here](https://github.com/torkel104/libstrangle), with help from stan, a gamingonlinux forum user, [info in this link](https://www.gamingonlinux.com/forum/topic/2096?page=1), to compile it correctly solved the issue. Limiting a game to a max of 60FPS completely eliminates whine coil sound on my machine.